# How to put space in the name of a slash command is nextcord?

Tags: discord, discord.py, nextcord

```
@nextcord.slash_command(name = 'avatar', description  = f' Display your avatar or a specific user avatar.')
async def get_user_avatar(self, ctx, user: nextcord.Member = None)
```

I want to have a slash command with a name like this: " user avatar " with a space between this words.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, `slash_command` names needs to be lowercase, between 1 and 32 characters long, and only consist of these symbols: a-z, 0-9, -, _, and other languages'/scripts' symbols.

Your best option would be to change it to: `user_avatar`.